# What are fantasy points for?

Tags: dota-2

I am playing dota 2 for nearly 3 years now, but I have never figured out what the fantasy points are for and how you get them. I've seen sometimes already in replays that I have earned up to 10 (not totally sure, long time ago) fantasy points.

Can someone tell me what the usage is and how do I get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.fantasyesports.us/dota-fantasy-points.html):

> In Fantasy Dota, players on a team earn Dota Fantasy Points based on the statistics they generate in actual Dota games.

It's kind of like fantasy football or baseball. There is a [fantasy Dota feature](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Fantasy_Dota).  You can earn points whenever one of these players participate in a tournament.

From the Wiki, it also states that you can win in game rewards for participating in fantasy Dota. A scoring section is also there for reference on how the points are actually calculated. They are:

- Kill = 0.3
- Death = -0.3
- Assist = 0.15
- Last Hit = 0.003
- Gold per minute =    0.002
- EXP per minute = 0.002
- Seconds of enemy stuns    = 0.07
- Every 1000 allied healing done = 0.4
- Tower Kill = 1
- Roshan Kill =    1
- First blood = 3

Comment: Now I finally know what those points are. Thank you!